# Does PCI-DSS require that the telnet client be uninstalled from a server

Tags: pci-dss

Often(not always) I see with my clients' PCI vulnerability assessments the telnet client being installed coming up as flagged, for both Windows and Linux based servers.

I understand why a telnet server would get flagged but the client being installed but not used for actual telnet-based communications I don't see why they would flag it.

For troubleshooting network connectivity there are other 3rd party tools you can use but when you're having remote users perform troubleshooting for you in an environment without a standard set of tools installed sometimes this can be a life-saver. Just have had this item on my list for awhile and would like to get some outside input/perspective.

Edit: To clarify this is meant in the context of using the telnet client as a troubleshooting tool to verify port access, not to actually use the telnet protocol. There are "better" tools for this, but as previously stated you can often wind up in a situation where using a quick telnet check can give you the info you need versus taking the time to download a heavier 3rd party utility. An "OpenSSH" server is not a suitable replacement for this use case.

Comment: There should be no need for telnet. You can check for connections on a port using [Powershell for Windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/560081/check-port-open-without-telnet), or you could use netcat / [snetcat](http://snetcat.sourceforge.net/) for *nix

Comment: @DNUCKLES yeah, let's take Telnet off and put Netcat on.  That'll confound those wily hackers!

Comment: @gowenfawr sorry should be ncat.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why you would want an insecure program/protocol like telnet when its easy to employ a secure alternative in the form of an open-SSH server.

Telnet has often been used to compromise a system even when the normal network operators did not use it. There simply is no way to secure a telnet session.

Since the telnet client of windows can be used through the COM system it has even been used to create remote callbacks to an attackers server. (e.a. make it easy for someone to actually do something with a compromised host) Only when its completely removed the risk is mitigated.

Update:

> Edit: To clarify this is meant in the context of using the telnet client as a troubleshooting tool to verify port access, not to actually use the telnet protocol. There are "better" tools for this, but as previously stated you can often wind up in a situation where using a quick telnet check can give you the info you need versus taking the time to download a heavier 3rd party utility. An "OpenSSH" server is not a suitable replacement for this use case.

For this use case a [cUrl](https://curl.haxx.se/) tool would better suffice. since you can get all the details (as opposed to some with telnet) and it is even lighter than telnet without the attached COM elements that telnet supports (yes you got the library, but that is small enough to put in an exploit and there for not a barrier for attackers).

The [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) would replace all functionality of telnet as a management tool (and remote access), and replace this with a secure alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think the PCI DSS prohibits the Telnet client, but I can see how an ASV might interpret [2.3.b](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2.pdf?agreement=true&time=1469103725143) as saying so:**

> 2.3.b Review services and parameter files on systems to determine that Telnet and other insecure remote-login commands are not available for
>   non-console access.

On the one hand, it says "...insecure remote-login **commands** are not available for non-console access."  The use of *command* instead of *service*, *daemon*, or *listener* in this sentence could easily be read as implying that Telnet *client software* should be made unavailable.

On the other hand, when it says "Review **services and parameter files** it's clearly implying that it's focused on making sure the service isn't configured to run and listen for connections - the Telnet client is not a service and I interpret that *parameter files* means things like `inetd.conf`, not `.telnetrc`.

Personally, I find that Telnet is increasingly deprecated by default... Windows 7 and RHEL 6 don't install it.  Frankly, I find it more concerning that Linux distributions are starting to install `nc` by default (RHEL has it as a dependency for some stupid program or other).

And I agree with you that Telnet is a useful quick-and-dirty debugging tool.  When you need to determine if firewalls or routing are confounding one of you connections, and just want to see what happens, `telnet` is fine and better than making `nc` or `nmap` available.  (And I disagree with @LvB in that protocol-specific tools fall short when non-common protocols get used - databases, proprietary protocols, etc.)

In the end, you can push back on your ASV, asking them to cite their reasoning and then (if it's as I've surmised above) arguing with them about it.  For such a trivial point, you may win without even having to fight much.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey OP is crystal clear about the server/client distinction; read his 2nd paragraph... (whether he's accurately understanding his ASV's concerns is of course another possibility, but "client" is the concern he is describing).

Comment: I have yet to see a protocol that I can not quickly test with the cUrl libraries.  telnet is also a protocol specific tool, you are just abusing it as a generic tool. and I never mentioned `nc` or `nmap`, in which we both agree are bad ideas to have on every system.

Comment: @LvB 1) Databases listeners, first and foremost, and proprietary binary protocols like Nimbus.  2) Yes.  Yes I am abusing it as a generic tool, because it works well as one, and because I don't want to put specific attack tools on my system. 3) You didn't mention `nc`/`nmap`, but others did and others will (in this question and in actual experience when faced with Telnet being taken away)

Comment: Why not use a real generic tool like the cUrl librarie and its CLI tool? it does exactly what you want without all the nifty tricks you can exploit using nc or nmap.